# Domain of this function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

The function is: $$y=\frac{x+6}{15-\sqrt{{x^2}-64}}$$
The **domain** is: $(-\infty,-17) \cup (-17,-8] \cup [8,17) \cup (17,\infty) $

The value inside the square root can't be negative, so I set up:

$$x^2-64 \geq0$$

$$(x-8)(x+8) \geq0$$

Then I found the roots, $x=8$ and $x=-8$, which are the only places where the function *may* change sign. Now I'm looking for the other part of the inequality,  the $x>0$ part, so I then set up a number line and tested numbers in three different regions: $$x<-8$$ $$-8\leq x \leq 8$$ $$x>8.$$

I know that in the  $-8\leq x \leq 8$ region, (interval notation: $[-8,8]$), 
 $x^2-64<0$, so that area is not part of the domain and I understand that part of the answer.
I don't understand where the $-17,17$, and $\infty$ part of the domain comes from.

Please explain, thanks.

Also, what would the range be?

Comment: You can not divide by zero!!! What is missing?

Comment: @Sigur can you please show the work? I'm really not seeing where the 17 comes from. I added the **domain** answer.

Comment: Since you can not divide by zero you have to remove $x$ such that the denominator is zero, that is, $\sqrt{x^2-64} =15$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that in the  $-8\leq x \leq 8$ region, (interval notation: $[-8,8]$),  $x^2-64<0$, so that area is not part of the domain and I understand that part of the answer.

This isn’t quite right: it’s in the open interval $(-8,8)$ that $x^2-64<0$, not the closed interval $[-8,8]$, so it’s $(-8,8)$ that is ruled out by the square root. That leaves $(-\infty,-8]\cup[8,\infty)$. However, the denominator of the fraction cannot be $0$, so $\sqrt{x^2-64}$ cannot be $15$, and $x^2-64$ cannot be $15^2=225$. Thus, $x^2$ cannot be $225+64=289=17^2$, and $x$ cannot be $\pm 17$. Removing $-17$ and $17$ from the set $(-\infty,-8]\cup[8,\infty)$ leaves

$$(-\infty,-17)\cup(-17,-8]\cup[8,17)\cup(17,\infty)\;.$$

Comment: I was trying to let him discover by himself. You typed a lot... lol

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** you need to consider the following

> $$ 15-\sqrt{x^2-64}\neq 0 \quad \cap   \quad  x^2  - 16 \geq 0 .$$

Comment: No idea what $x^2-16$ has to do with anything.